# Como hacer click en un boton de una web dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una web escrita en .net mvc, la misma en una parte de ella tiene un iframe la cual accede a otra web que no esta en el mismo dominio de mi web, lo que necesito es poder dar click en un boton de la web que abre dentro del iframe pero me da error de:

iframe uncaught domexception: blocked a frame with origin

Entiendo que por seguridad esto es asi, no mer sirve desactivar la seguridad del navegador pues entonces en todos los clientes que usen mi web tienen que desabilitar eso.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('miiframe');
var htmlIframe = iframe.contentDocument;
```

Sin resultados

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/92267/16597) te sea de ayuda.

Comment: vi algo parecido a eso, pero todo lo que encuentro es para traer y enviar datos, lo que no veo es hacer click en un boton especifico de la web que abre dentro del iframe